# Do I use Association or Aggregation?

Tags: uml, associations, aggregation, class-diagram

I have a question related to aggregation and association. Each movie *has* one director, and each play *has* one main actor. The relationship is definitely association... But I think aggregation should be used. I was reading about the relationships and found the pond and duck example. This example made me feel that director, or main character are a part of movie/play. My friend claims this isn't example of it. May someone please explain, because I am confused... Thank you kindly in advance.

As explained, I was reading more on aggregation and association. I found example of pond and duck that had aggregation used, as an example of: if you destroy pond as a container, ducks live on. Isn't the same with the movie and director, play and main actor?

Comment: Actually, there are three variants: the normal association (no diamond), the normal aggregation, sometimes called shared aggregation (open diamond) and the composition (filled diamond). The rule that if you destroy the container, you also destroy the contents only applies to the composition.